# How to perform an action within a page in Rails without rendering a new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I'm trying to add a contact user popup box which delivers an email message to a user.

I have the javascript in place to display the popup form, which is itself a partial.

When the user clicks submit on the contact form it calls a controller action which delivers the mail. After submitting the message I want to stay on the same page, but hide the popup box. My problem is that I can't get the controller action which delivers the mail not to render its own view. I tried

```
render nothing: true
```

But that simply renders a blank page.

My form is set up as follows

```
= form_tag({:controller => 'users', :action => 'contact_user'}, :method => 'put') do
```

And in my routes config I have

```
resources :users
  collection do
     put 'contact_user'
  end
```

Comment: what does the controller action look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you submit your form via AJAX, you can do what you're trying to do.

Adding `:remote => true` to your form will accomplish this:

```
= form_tag({:controller => 'users', :action => 'contact_user'}, :method => 'put', :remote => true) do
```

Now, the form submission will hit your controller as an AJAX request.  You should then be able to either render nothing, as you suggested, or even do something like render a `.js.erb` to execute some Javascript instead (say, to hide the popup you're talking about).