# Bypass missing template error ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model, render

I want to run a create function without rendering a new template posts/create, I simply want to load the current one and reload the current page.

I've tried adding render :nothing => true as well as render nothing: true to the bottom of my create function but I'm still getting a missing template error (it keeps trying to look for posts/create.html.erb)

What can I do to bypass this? again, I just want to run a function...

```
def create()
    new_post = Post.new
    new_post.content = params[:content]
    new_post.group_id = params[:group_id]
    new_post.poster_id = session[:user_id]
    Group.find(params[:group_id]).posts.append(new_post)
    User.find(session[:user_id]).posts.append(new_post)
    redirect_to controller: 'group', action: 'view', group_id: params[:group_id]
    render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: You should remove `redirect_to` statement. Also against `render nothing: true` more appropriate is `head :ok`.

Comment: Why do you have a redirect and a render, I don't think that's going to help..

Comment: I'm just trying everything lol, I can't get rails to stop looking for a template. It does not work with one or the other or both

Comment: All i want to do is run this create function inside my model and pass it some arguments, then reload the current page

Comment: are you in Rails 4.2? and do you have byebug gem included in your Gemfile?

Comment: The other way is Ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858463/how-to-perform-an-action-within-a-page-in-rails-without-rendering-a-new-page - an, sorry, you do want to reload page, I misread

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario yes and yes

Comment: @Riptyde4, ok can you insert this line -> byebug <- just before redirect_to controller: 'group', action...? And then submit the page with the form, and then you should notice that it will pause because of byebug. Now that its paused. Can you enter in byebug console: `redirect_to controller: 'group', action: 'view', group_id: params[:group_id]` and then tell me what will show up.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario it doesn't pause

Comment: @Riptyde4 I guessed that would be the case... Then that means your create method didnt get called. Just so that we are sure that it doesn't get called, can you append byebug at the very start (so append byebug just below def create), and then check if it will pause. If it doesn't still pause and show byebug console on the window where you run `rails server`, then that means `def create` really didn't get called. If that is the case, it is difficult to help you with this. I will need you to check on this matter first.

Comment: It says missing template even with ajax method

Comment: no pause either.... @Jay-ArPolidario

Comment: this seems like such an incredibly simple thing to need to do, why is this so difficult with rails

Comment: @Riptyde4 it sounds like you aren't getting to the create method at all.  Double-check the form that is supposed to be sending information to this route.  Could you post your form code?